# Programatically post xml data to a resource and serialize the result

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am trying to work with a relatively new API from a 3rd party provider. The basic usage is to POST a query, formatted as xml. So, theoretically, the POST uri would look like:

http://provideraddress.com/?xml=*myxml*

In turn, I should receive an xml formatted response.

It's been awhile, so I'm struggling with the best way to do this (in fact, I could care less about "best", and would settle for just getting the thing to work).

So far I've attempted to use WebClient as well as WebRequest. The latest attempt uses the latter, after building the xml data manually as a string. I've tried appending the "xml" param to the uri, as well as writing it to a StreamWriter. First, I get some sort of WebResponse object back, but the content length is always -1, and the content type is reported as text/html, neither of which seems appropriate. Second, I'm unsure of how I would parse the WebResponse or serialize it's content into my object graph.

I've googled quite a bit and the examples are erratic or outdated. I don't want to deal with file system writing. Ideally, I'd be able to fill my own request object graph, serialize that into xml, send the POST, and receive something that can be serialized back into my respond object graph.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I'm not asking anyone to do my work for me, I'm just looking for a solid resource.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use a WebClient:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
            string xml = @"<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>";
            string url = "http://provideraddress.com/?xml=myxml";
            string response = client.UploadString(url, xml);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Now as far as generating the request string is concerned you could use one of the many methods available in .NET: [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx), [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) (this one starts getting old, you should probably prefer a XDocument instead) or serialize an object graph into string using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), ... Same for the response XML => you could parse it using XDocument, XmlReader, XmlDocument or deserialize it back to an object graph using XmlSerializer.

Now if the server responds with content type `text/html` and returns you no response that is probably because the XML you POSTed was not in the format that the server expected, you didn't supply some HTTP request header that the server expected, the server encountered some error processing your request, ... Read the documentation of the 3rd party API and ensure that you are respecting its format. There are some APIs that might require an authentication first. So that you would need to send a request to some url with a username and password and if the authentication succeeds the server sends you back a token or a cookie that you should send on all subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I've tried that method. I'm starting to think something is wrong with the resource I'm trying to hit. I've reached out to their support group.